# pairwise balanced design has block size related to the number of elements.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

A pairwise balanced design is a set of elements $X$ and set of blocks $A$ such that each pair of elements of $X$ occurs in exactly $\lambda$ blocks.

I am trying to solve the following problem: Given a PBD with $|X|=v$, where $v \equiv 2\mod 3$, $\lambda = 1$ and every block $B \in A$ is of size $k$ or size $3$, then $k\equiv 2\mod 3$.

I'm really not sure where to start. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Where did you see this problem?  It's expected that you present your own thoughts about an approach, especially the difficulty you encountered in trying the problem yourself.

Comment: I really couldn't get any further than this. It is an exercise in the book "introduction to combinatorial designs"

Comment: The book by Stinson? Are you comfortable with the level of linear algebra used in his book?

Comment: I believe that it is by W.D. Wallis

Comment: Does the book use the incidence matrix (between blocks and elements) to present computations?  I would start by expressing all the assumptions you are given in algebraic terms.  An interesting property of PBD's is that two blocks can only intersect in a single point or be disjoint (why?).

Comment: Alright, I will try that! Thank you. Is this the case for all PBD's, or just those with $\lambda = 1$, where $\lambda$ is the number of times a pair of points occurs within a block? (I see why for $\lambda = 1$)

Comment: Just those with $\lambda=1$, as here! Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $m$ blocks of size $k$ and $n$ of size $3$, then  $3n=\binom{v}{2}-m\binom{k}{2}$, notice $\binom{v}{2}$ is congruent to $1\bmod 3$. Unless $k$ is congruent to $2\bmod 3$ we shall have $\binom{k}{2}$ is a multiple of three. This would mean $\binom{v}{2}-m\binom{k}{2}$ would not be a multiple of $3$, and $n$ would then not be an integer.